# Using testCompile output from other subproject (Gradle Kotlin DSL)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have some utility files in the test sources in one of my gradle subproject and would like to use them in an other subproject.
My "source" subproject is called `core`, while the one uses it is called `tem`.

I try to migrate and integrate the [following example](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/i-cant-seem-to-share-test-code-between-projects-in-a-multi-project-build/14874/2):

```
In your Server project:

configurations {
    testArtifacts.extendsFrom testCompile
}
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier "test"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}
artifacts {
    testArtifacts testJar
}

In your ServerWeb project:

testCompile project(path: ":Server", configuration: 'testArtifacts')
```

As far as I get is making the conversation. I added the following to my `core.gradle.kts`:

```
val testConfig = configurations.create("testArtifacts") {
    extendsFrom(configurations["testCompile"])
}

tasks.register("testJar", Jar::class.java) {
    classifier += "test"
    from(sourceSets["test"].output)
}

artifacts {
    add("testArtifacts", tasks.named<Jar>("testJar") )
}
```

And tried to refer to it in `tem.gradle.kts`:

```
testImplementation(project(":core", "testArtifacts"))
```

It compiles, but I still can't access the classes from core.

Where did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

Most of your code should be OK

But you must define classesDirs for jar

```
tasks.register<Jar>("testJar") {
    dependsOn("testClasses")
    archiveBaseName.set("${project.name}-test")
    from(sourceSets["test"].output.classesDirs)
}
```

I also added depends on testClasses to be sure that classes are compiled.

You can test that jar is OK by executing **testJar** task. Then verify that generated jar contains your classes. If you make mistake with from method call then you get empty jar.

Answer (score 2):

The following configuration worked for me to include both the test classes and test resources:

core build.gradle.kts

```
val testConfig = configurations.create("testArtifacts") {
    extendsFrom(configurations["testCompile"])
}   

tasks.register("testJar", Jar::class.java) {
    dependsOn("testClasses")
    classifier += "test"
    from(sourceSets["test"].output)
}   

artifacts { 
    add("testArtifacts", tasks.named<Jar>("testJar") )
}
```

tem build.gradle.kts

```
testImplementation(project(":core", "testArtifacts"))
```